# Using Regex to Match first period outside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a project where I need to traverse over a static html file and pull out information for each song listed on the page.

I have three different files I have to work with, and about 3000 total songs.
Each song is contained in a format similar to the following:

```html
<p>
    <b>{Song Name}</b>
    <br/>
    <b>{Song Artist(s)/Description }</b>
</p>
```

Its easy enough to get the song name, but I also want to separate out the artist(s) from the description as well.
The artist section usually starts with the word "By" and ends with a period like so:
`By {Song Artist}.`

However, the artist may not be plain text, it might be contained within an html anchor tag. There is also the possibility of more than one artist. If the multiple artists are all just plain text, its a simple match.
The issue i am having, and where this question comes in is when the multiple artists are mixed between html and plain text.

The following is an example of the description for one of the songs.

```html
By <a href="www.example.com">An artist</a> and another artist. A <a href="www.example.com">song</a> about the<a href="www.example.com"> {insert issue here}</a> in <a href="www.example.com">{insert place here}</a>. "...some meaningful text here..."
```

Originally I came up with this regex to match all of the songs on the page. It works for most of them, but the above example is a case where it doesn't work.

`^.+?(?:<a.*?<\/a>)?\.`

It matches the start of the string and as few characters as possible until it sees a period. The optional non-capturing group is to make sure a period doesn't get matched inside of the anchor.

This doesn't work in the above example because it won't match any characters past the anchor tag except for a period. It ends up matching more then just the artists, it matches into the description of the song where it sees a period after an anchor tag.

I also tried adding a lazy selector after the anchor tag: `^.+?(?:<a.*?<\/a>)?.*?\.` but since the anchor is optional, it will just end up matching the first period, even if it's inside the anchor.

I'm looking for a way to match from the start of the string to the first period that is outside of an anchor tag. I need to match the full html because I will need access to the artist's website if it exists. I do not need to capture the link in this instance, I only need to separate the artist section from the rest of the description using the period as a delimiter.

I would like to at least match the following instances:

```html
By an artist.
By an artist and another artist.
By <a href="www.example.com">artist</a>.
By <a href="www.example.com">artist</a> and another artist.
By artist and <a href="www.example.com">another artist</a>.
By <a href="www.example.com">Artist 1</a> and <a href="www.example.com">Artist 2</a>.
```

Is this possible to do with just regex? Or since i am working with this in the browser, and have access to the element nodes should I just loop over the different nodes trying to piece together what is outside an anchor?

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**:

Given the complexity of this now extended question, this answer is probably not a foolproof solution. But I hope it contains some pointers of where to go.

For each track there is an array `artists` that will list the name and - as far as available - the URL for each artist individually. Further links, as might be found in the "description" will *not* be picked up.

```js
const res=[...document.querySelectorAll("p")].reduce((a,c)=>{
   let t=c.querySelectorAll("b"),[_,art,de]=t[1]. textContent.match(/By (.*?)\. (.*)/);
   let urls={};
   let ls=t[1].querySelectorAll("a").forEach(l=>urls[l.textContent]=l.getAttribute("href"));
   let artists=art.split(/ and |, /).map(ar=>{
    let ao={name:ar};
    if(urls[ar]) ao.url=urls[ar];
    return ao;
   });
   a.push({title:t[0].textContent, artists,description:de});
   return a;
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

```html
<p>
  <b>A song title</b>
  <br>
  <b>By an artist. Some great music here.</b>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Another song title</b>
  <br>
  <b>By an artist and another artist. Some Soul here. And some more text. And more.</b>
</p>

<p>
  <b>A third song title</b>
  <br>
  <b>By <a href="www.example1.com">artist</a>. Listen to this on <a href="streaming service.com">stream here</a> for free.</b>
</p>

<p>
  <b>And yet another song</b>
  <br>
  <b>By <a href="www.example2.com">artist</a> and another artist. What else do you want?</b>
</p>

<p>
  <b>A a last one</b>
  <br>
  <b>By artist and <a href="www.example3.com">another artist</a>. Wow, what a track!</b>
</p>
```

By making use of the known DOM structure and analysing it using `document.querySelectorAll()` we end up with smaller pieces from which we take the `.textContent` and ultimately separate one of the resulting strings by matching it with  the pattern `/(.*?)\. (.*)/` which will return a first "non-greedy" group matching anything up to the first `\.` , followed by the second ("greedy") group `(.*)` containing the description of the track.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it looks like I forgot to mention I also need to preserve the link to the artist's page if it exists. I plan to process the artist string by separating the artists if there are multiple and grouping them with their associated link if it exists.

Comment: Please check again ... Obviously, without a more concrete example it is difficult to determine, how to process the text.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't tell me who the url belongs to. It could also grab the wrong url if the artist section doesn't contain an anchor tag, but later in the description an anchor appears. I need to add this to my question, but multiple artists with their own links could be a possibility.

Comment: You are right. But how do you expect us to answer a question that hasn't even been asked in the first place? Please keep questions as clear and simple as possible. You should also not change their direction or increase the scope afterwards. If necessary, feel free to post a follow-up question, focussing on the artist/URL problem.

Comment: What about my latest version? Have you checked? Now all artists are listed with URLs - as far as available.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you must have misunderstood my question from the beginning. I asked for help on finding a regular expression to obtain the start of the string to the first period outside of an anchor tag. I only wanted the raw content and was going to manipulate the data later. However, your answer is going beyond the scope of this question by breaking the data into its different parts immediately. The scope of the original question didn't change, I only provided more examples of situations that could occur within that scope.

Comment: Your updated answer does appear to solve the issue I was having. Thank you.